# What is the square root of $(-5)\cdot(-5)$ and how is it different from $\sqrt{(-5)^2}$?

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

What is the square root of $(-5)\cdot(-5)$ and how is it different from $\sqrt{(-5)^2}$? Can anybody explain?

Comment: To me, it looks like you wrote the same thing twice. What am I missing?

Comment: $\sqrt{(-5)^2} = 5$

Comment: Use *MathJax* if you want us to help on such a question.

Comment: $(-5)^2=25$. So both expressions are equal to $5$. Perhaps your confusion arises from the difference between _the_ square root of $25$ (which is conventionally defined as $5$) and _a_ square root of $25$ (which could be $5$ or $-5$).

Comment: I think square root of a number is both positive and negative , but the radical of a number(positive number , here radicand is -5*-5=25, is positive) is always positive, this is causing confusion

Comment: Sir I tried to use mathjax, could not succeed as i think

Comment: Yes, I realised this was probably the source of the confusion, so I edited my comment accordingly. I admit that the difference is subtle.

Comment: I think basic is missing, its not a matter of "a" or "The ". Its a matter of principle square root and negative square root. I know this, i am just trying to apply is to find square root of (-x)^2, i am unable to explain with logic that square root of (-x)^2 is +x and -x or i am wrong somewhere?

Comment: Ha! I see what you did there: "i am unable to explain with logic that square root of..." You left out the article! This is not English as we know it, but it cleverly renders the question unanswerable! It is indeed a question of _a_ or _the_. I don't know how Russian and related languages handle this problem, not having grammatical articles to fall back on, but that's how it works in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let us get to $$(-5)^2=25$$

Well $25$ has two square roots  Positive one which we denote as $$\sqrt {25} =5$$ and a negative one which is denoted by $$-\sqrt {25} =-5$$ 
A common mistake happens when someone writes $$\sqrt {25} = \pm 5$$

Now the equation $$x^2=25$$ has two solutions and we may write them as $$x=\pm 5$$
One good formula to have in mind is that $$\sqrt {x^2} = |x|$$  which results in $$-\sqrt {x^2} = -|x|$$

Answer (score 4):

We may differentiate  "two kinds" of square rooting:

**arithmetical root**
It belongs to questions like $\sqrt{25}$, $\sqrt{49}$, $\sqrt[3]{-8}$ with answers 5 , 7 and -2 respectively. It will always be as same sign of the argument.

**algebraical root**

It belongs to the set of numbers which satisfies some equation like $x^2=4$ with values $2$ and $-2$, or $x^2=25$ with values $5$ and $-5$.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental theorem of algebra tells us that a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots. For your example, the polynomial is $x^2 - 25$. It is of degree 2 (because that's the highest exponent) and it therefore has two roots, two values of $x$ such that $x^2 - 25 = 0$. Those are $x = -5$ and $x = 5$.

However, we have agreed, for convention through several decades if not centuries, that the square root symbol is for a function that gives us the *principal* square root. In your example that would be 5, not $-5$. Maybe that feels arbitrary to you, but that's the convention.

Hence, given a real number $c$, we find that $\sqrt{c^2} = \sqrt{(-c)^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Every positive real number has exactly two distinct square roots. They are opposites.

If $r$ is a positive real number, the symbol "$\sqrt{r}$" denotes the positive square root of $r$, and so "$-\sqrt{r}$" denotes its opposite, the root which is negative.

Note that "positive real number" does not include zero. For the special case $r=0$, there is only one square root, which is again zero. This is just because $0$ and $-0$ are the same number. By convention "the" square root is the positive root (or the only root, in the case of $0$).

However, this convention vanishes when the roots aren't real, simply because complex numbers in general don't have signs; they aren't "positive" or "negative" (unless they are actually real numbers).

Negative real numbers (and generally speaking, complex numbers which are not nonnegative real numbers) do not have real square roots. Still, it is true that every nonzero complex number $c$ has exactly two square roots, and they are opposites. In theory, they could be denoted by "$\sqrt{c}$" and "$-\sqrt{c}$"; the only problem is that there is no natural way to decide which one is represented by the symbol "$\sqrt{c}$" (once that's decided, the other root is always just its opposite).

For example, $1-i$ and $-1+i$ are the two square roots of $-2i$ because $(1-i)^2=-2i$ and $(-1+i)^2=-2i$. They are opposites, as always, but which one is $\sqrt{-2i}$? There is no universal agreement.

Finally, if you don't specify which is which, you can certainly speak of *both* square roots together as "$\pm\sqrt{c}$" and leave the ambiguity alone.

---

Answering your question: both symbols you wrote are $5$. That's just because $(-5)\cdot(-5)$ and $(-5)^2$ are both the number $25$, and "the" square root of $25$ is $5$.